# Error using pip to install frameworks,etc

Tags: python, pip

every time i try to install something with pip i get the error "You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 18.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command."

i use the command given but i only get "Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\users\iagol\pycharmprojects\devinsanta challenge\venv\lib\site-packages (18.1)

according to that file path it is referring to another test project of mine... Shouldnt pip be updated to all my projects?

(please excuse my noobness, first timer here lol)

Comment: It's not an *error*, just a notice. And you should invoke `pip` the same way you do when you try to install something. I.e. `pip install foo` and `python -m pip install foo` may refer to different Python versions/pip installations. Do `... install --upgrade pip` with the same "`...`" you always use to install something via pip.

Comment: yeah i invoked pip, i think, my comand was "pip install virtualenv" then i get the version notice

Answer (score 1):

I think you're updating the pip in your virtual environment, but not the one installed in the system.

To make sure you're using the pip in your virtual environment, you need to activate it first.  The activation script is in ./venv/bin.

Comment: cant seem to find that activation script... my /venv folder only has a pyvenv.cfg and a pip-selfcheck.json, and some other folders...